# Rails: Can't start the rails console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, ubuntu

I am currently using **Rails 5.2.3** and **Ruby 2.5.0** on an application running on Ubuntu 18.04 production server, but when I run the command

```
rails c --environment=production
```

the command terminal gets stuck and I have to abort the process by holding down Ctrl + C keys together.

It, however, outputs the error below:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
    16: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    15: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    14: from /home/deploy/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    12: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    11: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
     9: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     7: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     6: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
     5: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     4: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `call'
     3: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in `warm_run'
     2: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in `run'
     1: from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `verify_server_version'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
```

I have tried a few solutions but none seem to work for now, I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem that preloads a rails application in the background, however, it's not advisable to run it in a production environment

**Here's how I solved the issue:**

I installed/re-installed the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem:

```
gem install spring
```

I then upsprung (removed the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem from) the `bin/` executables:

```
bin/spring binstub --remove --all
```

Or

```
spring binstub --remove --all
```

You can now run the command below to get into rails console in production

```
rails c --environment=production
```

Also, to avoid this from occurring in subsequent occasions endeavour to make sure that the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem is only present in `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile.

Moreso, when you're in production make sure you always provide the `--without development test` argument to the `bundle install` command

```
bundle install --without development test
```

and not the usual or common

```
bundle install
```